# Align img and ul list to be next to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to present an item for the **mobile** version of my website and what I want to accomplish is having a picture of the listed item, and a bulleted  list with some basic info on the item like so...

```
ITEM TITLE
--------------
|            |  <bullet>Material  <bullet>Origin
|            |  material          origin
|   ITEM     |
|            |  <bullet>Other info header <bullet>Other info
|            |  description               description
--------------
```

my HTML code for this so far is like this:

```
<div class="items">
        <h1>All items</h1>
        <div class="item">
            <h2><u>Item Title</u></h2>
            <div class="left">
                <a href=""><img src="path/to/img" alt="item picture" width="120" height="190"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div class="item-details">
                    <ul>
                        <lh>Material</lh>
                        <li>Gold</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <lh>Origin</lh>
                        <li>USA</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <lh>Other info</lh>
                        <li>Hello</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <lh>Date manufactured</lh>
                        <li>400 B.C.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS for this is:

```
.item {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    display: table
}

.item-details ul {
    float: left;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

.item-details ul lh {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.itemn-details ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

But, the unordered list appears to be too big or something, so, html skips some lines and put's its under the picture which is **not** what I wanted.

Any ideas on how I am going to fix this?

Comment: Try removing the right class from this div `<div class="right">`

Comment: @j08691 It's kinda correct. but I can't have for instance 2 elements on the same line which is vital, in order to give to the user the most amount of information in the shortest possible lines.

Comment: Can you update your question and embed a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so that we can see the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats are a little strange to work with. I managed to get the look I think you are looking for by removing the float from the "right" div and instead giving it "margin-left:auto;". This pushes it to the right, but allows for the elements inside to stack as the viewport shrinks. I think this happens because the browser isn't trying to float the entire div to the right of the element next to it anymore.

Hope this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: That was exactly it! Your analysis, also furthered my understanding of how those elements work! Thank you!

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help.

Comment: Also, it might be worth revisiting the code later to rework it a bit. In code there are many ways to skin a cat, some better than others. I think recreating this layout using columns, display:inline-block, and text-align might be a better solution in the long run. Good luck!